# How to attach a managed policy to a lambda function in serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

How can I attach a managed policy to a lambda function?

I tried:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  role: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoReadOnly
```

But this resulted in the following error:

> An error occurred while provisioning your stack: GaDashextractLambdaFunction
>        - 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoReadOnly'
>        at 'role' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must
>        satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:aws:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@-_/]+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the error -- it expects `role` instead of `policy`.

IAM Policies are documents that define permissions and can't be attached directly to lambda functions. Create an [IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) and [attach the managed policy to the role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-using.html#attach-managed-policy-console).  Think of the role as a container for your policy; policies can't be attached directly to lambda functions, but roles can. You can freely attach and detach managed and inline policies to your roles.

**Option 1: Fix this error from AWS Console with a pre-defined policy:**

- Create a new IAM Role for your lambda function.
- During creation, attach the `AmazonCognitoReadOnly` managed policy.
- Replace the ARN in your `role` definition with your new role's ARN.

**Option 2: Define actions of AmazonCognitoReadOnly policy in serverless.yml:**

This effectively converts the managed policy to an inline policy. *Warning: this is untested.*

```
provider:
  ...
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - cognito-identity:Describe*
        - cognito-identity:Get*
        - cognito-identity:List*
        - cognito-idp:Describe*
        - cognito-idp:AdminGetUser
        - cognito-idp:List*
        - cognito-sync:Describe*
        - cognito-sync:Get*
        - cognito-sync:List*
        - iam:ListOpenIdConnectProviders
        - iam:ListRoles
        - sns:ListPlatformApplication
      Resource: *
```

**Further Reading:**

- [AWS Documentation - AWS Lambda Permissions Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#lambda-intro-execution-role)
- [AWS Documentation - Create the (IAM) Execution Role (Tutorial)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-create-iam-role.html)

Comment: Thanks i went down the second path. Hoped there was a shortcut to attach them directly

Answer (score 6):

You can. Just provide the ARN in the ManagedPolicyArns of a Role resource.

```
Resources:
  RoleName:
    ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess"
```

For policies applied to all functions:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  iamManagedPolicies:
    - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess"
```

Comment: `iamManagedPolicies` is now deprectaed, see https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations#grouping-iam-settings-under-provideriam. The recommended approach is now using `provider.iam.role.managedPolicies` instead.